# Conversion Value - Google Tag Manager

Tags: tracking

I created a custom html tag and it's firing on my completion order page however I can't seem to get the {{Total Amount}} to pull. This is a variable we created and it works with adwords conversion tracking tag but I can't seem to get it to pull in the amount using this custom html tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var money = {{Total Amount}};
document.writeln('<img src="https://app.bronto.com/public/?q=stream_conversion&fn=Mail_Conversion&id=userid&type=$&description=sale&money='+money+'" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt="brontoconversiontracking"/>');
</script>
```

Can you please explain to me if I'm missing a step?? This is the only code we use to push the amount from the conformation page which is stored in ssp applications order_wizard_cart_summary.txt it pulls in the subtotal for Adwords conversion tracking but not the custom html script.

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({'subtotal':'<%= summary.total_formatted %>'});
</script>
```

I have a Total Amount dataLayer variable in google tag manager and the "Data Layer Variable Name" is subtotal.

Comment: Did you use debug mode to check what data is in {{Total Amount}} in the moment when you want to fire your custom html tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you make push() to dataLayer after the macro is used you'll get no data. Try debug mode to see the state of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this guys,

```
<script>
var price = '<%= summary.total_formatted %>';
var pri = price.replace("$","");
dataLayer.push({'subtotal':pri});
</script>
```

works prefect :)